# how to merge x views in one template

Tags: django, python-3.5

I'm trying to use two views list(post_list and classification_list) in a template called blogpage. here's what I've done to solve the problem, however it didn't work:

```
class GenViewList(ListView):
    model = Posting,Classification
    template_name = 'Blog/blogpage.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context=super(BlogViewList,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['latest_post_list']=Posting.objects.filter().order_by('-id')[:30]
        context['classification_list']=Classification.objects.all().order_by('id')
        return context
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just make it a `TemplateView`

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

class GenViewList(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'Blog/blogpage.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context=super(BlogViewList,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['latest_post_list']=Posting.objects.filter().order_by('-id')[:30]
        context['classification_list']=Classification.objects.all().order_by('id')
        return context
```

Answer (score 0):

ListView doesn't work with 2 different models. You can provide your `get_queryset`, but in the way you construct your `get_context` seems you need something different like `TemplateView`